# Using async with Node

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, express, node-async

I'm attempting to write a simple validation script in Node where error codes are added to an `error` array when certain validation checks fail. To complicate things, I also have a function called `translate` which makes a database call and returns the full text associated with an error code (translated into the specified language). In order to achieve this, I'm using the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) library.

Unfortunately, the following code always results in an empty array, even when validation should fail. I've confirmed independently that my `translate` function works. Any ideas why this isn't working?

```
app.post("/user", function(req, res) {

  var error = [];

  if (req.body.username == "") {
    error.push("username_required");
  }

  if (req.body.password == "") {
    error.push("password_required");
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < error.length; i++) {
    error[i] = function(callback) {
      translate(error[i], req.language, function(text) {
        callback(null, text);
      });
    };
  }

  async.parallel(error, function(error, results) {
    res.send(results);
  });

});

translate = function(code, language, callback) {
  var code = database.escape(code);
  var language = database.escape(language);
  database.query("SELECT content FROM text WHERE language = 'en' AND code = " + code, function(error, row) {
    callback(row[0].content);
  });
}
```

Comment: This is the infamous closure problem.  Javascritp does not have block scope.

Comment: I see. Any suggestions on an alternate approach?

Comment: Wrap the callback in a function that creates a closure around its parameter.

Comment: http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/12/04/achieving-block-scope-with-immediate-functions-in-javascript/

Comment: Okay, I'm trying to wrap my mind around this. In general, am I thinking about things in the wrong way? Is this something that is common when using Node and JavaScript?

Comment: Personally think you're on the right track. JavaScript scope in that case can be tricky; SLaks is right, a simple function that creates new scope would fix it. However, I'd change `async.parallel` to an `async.map` that uses the *original* `error` array before you turn them into functions.

Comment: @BrandonTilley: Great idea. I'm trying that now...

Comment: @BrandonTilley: async.map worked perfectly. I went ahead and posted my solution, but I'd be happy to give you the credit if you want to post an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, [async.map](https://github.com/caolan/async#map) did the trick. Here's my final solution:

```
app.post("/user", function(req, res) {

  var error = [];

  if (!req.body.username) {
    error.push("username_required");
  }

  if (!req.body.password) {
    error.push("password_required");
  }

  async.map(error, function(error, callback) {
    translate(error, req.language, function(text) {
      callback(null, text);
    });
  }, function(error, results) {
    res.send(results);
  });

});
```

Comment: If you can modify `translate` to call the callback in traditional Node.js style (`callback(error, result)`), you can make it even shorter: `translate(error, req.language, callback);`